# Запуск исполняемых файлов Unix из любой папки – OS X

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

Суть в том, что я не могу запустить с терминала команду, находящуюся в папке. При том нахожусь я именно в ней. Пишет что команда не найдена, и все тут. Пробовал копировать в /usr/local/bin – команда исполняется, однако неверные пути при выполнении – оно и понятно, так как запускаю консольную утилиту artisan на проекте laravel.

Буду признателен за помощь. Все что смог найти в интернете – "список самых востребованных команд bash", "команды терминала, которые должен знать каждый" и т.п.

Comment: начало файла покажи

Comment: Какого именно файла?

Comment: вы не можете запустить команду, которая находится в какой то папке, верно? вы имеете ввиду функцию некую (или скрпит) ?  тогда напишите вашу команду. пожалуйста

Comment: <?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader
| for our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll require it
| into the script here so that we do not have to worry about the
| loading of any our classes "manually". Feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';

Comment: Ужасно показал) Я имею в виду скрипт, который в файле

Comment: вот так: `./имяфайла` либо `php имяфайла`  если нет shebang line  у него в начале / и нет +x бита на выполнение

Comment: скажите какую команду запускайте и какой результат видите (обновите вопрос)

Comment: strangeqargo – спасибо! Не понял только немного вторую часть. Можно ли как нибудь обойтись без "php" в начале и запускать как обычную команду терминала? Разумеется когда файл находится в активной папке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. не путайте команду и файл. команда не находится в "каталоге" команда - это ключевое слово для [оболочки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash) (echo, например)
2. чтобы запустить файл, у которого установлен [executable](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) bit (chmod +x имяФайла), напишите `./имяФайла` (юникс ищет и запускает исполняемые файлы только в каталогах о которых знает из переменной `PATH`), а `./` помогает ему догадаться, что нужен текущий каталог.
3. если у вас php(питон, и т.д.)-файл, просто напишите `php имяФайла`
4. если у вашего php-скрипта в начале установлен так называемый [shebang](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3_(Unix)) line (`#!/usr/bin/php`)  и сам файл исполняемый (chmod +x), то ./имяФайла должно сработать на выполнение (не нужно будет писать `php имяФайла`)

Comment: Еще раз большое спасибо!